# datatable as an itemsource for datagrid in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I set a datagrid control values from a datatable ?

I use this source

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ObjDataTableDefaultViewProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ObjDataTableDefaultView", typeof(System.Data.DataView), typeof(Window1), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata());

    public System.Data.DataView ObjDataTableDefaultView
    {
        get { return (System.Data.DataView)GetValue(ObjDataTableDefaultViewProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ObjDataTableDefaultViewProperty, value); }
    }
    private void CreateObjDataTable()
    {
        try
        {
            ObjDataTableDefaultView = table.DefaultView;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

But it has got an error message and the program stops,

> A first chance exception of type
>   'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in
>   PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: Cannot create instance of 'Window1' defined in
>   assembly 'ReadSky, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'. Exception has been thrown by the target of an
>   invocation.  Error in markup file 'Window1.xaml' Line 1 Position 9.

```
 My XAML

<Window x:Class="ReadSky.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="296" Width="738" xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit">
    <Grid>
        <my:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="36,30,39,90" Name="gridCtrl" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" IsReadOnly="True" RowBackground="Gray" AlternatingRowBackground="White" ItemsSource="{Binding ObjDataTableDefaultView, ElementName=uc, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Please can you post your XAML

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
 <DataGrid Name="grid" AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" />     

 public DataTable TableData {
        get {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("col1");
            dt.Columns.Add("col2");
            dt.Rows.Add(new string[] {"val1", "val2"});
            return dt;
        }
    }

 grid.DataContext = TableData;
```